# How to ""save" the result in a text file in java

Tags: java, file-io

I want to save the output result to a text file and retrieve it whenever I want to. For writing the output to .txt, I have used the following code.

```
 import java.io.*;

    class FileOutputDemo {  

        public static void main(String args[])
        {              
                FileOutputStream out; // declare a file output object
                PrintStream p; // declare a print stream object

                try
                {
                        // Create a new file output stream
                        // connected to "myfile.txt"
                        out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt");

                        // Connect print stream to the output stream
                        p = new PrintStream( out );

                        p.append ("This is written to a file");

                        p.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        System.err.println ("Error writing to file");
                }
        }
    }
```

It is working fine and the intended text file is written. But whenever I re-compile the program, the new output is written whereas the previous output is deleted. Is there a way to save the output of the previously written file and to pick up from where the previous text file left off (After re-compiling it).

Comment: This is not a paid service that you will get quick response to your queries. This is a community!!

Comment: Take a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Comment: Expectations may not always be met.

Comment: setting file output stream to TRUE means , it will append your data , and setting it to false will simple rewrite the file , its like deleting old one and creating a new one

Comment: PS. If you're new to stackoverflow, it's nice etiquette to 'tick' the question as answered, if you are happy with one of the answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt", true);
```

Javadoc: [FileOutputStream.append(String name,
                        boolean append)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

Comment: Are you copying my JavaDoc link, mr. steve? ;)

Answer (score 0):

See `new FileOutputStream(file, true);` (or `fileName` as name instead of a `file` object) as [documented in the constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#constructor_summary) for the class.

### Further tips

#### 1. Reporting

Change:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.err.println ("Error writing to file");
}
```

To:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The latter provides more information with less typing.

#### 2. GUI

If this app. is to have a GUI, the text would typically be input by the user in a `JTextArea`.  That component extends from `JTextComponent` which offers almost a 'one-liner' for saving and loading text:

1. [`read(Reader, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29)
2. [`write(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29)

Comment: Are u copying my answer, mister 4-gold medals? ;)